# How to get LightMuted color from Vibrant js?

Tags: javascript

I am using https://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/ to get colors from images, on their website they show examples where they also show the whitest color (LightMuted) however I can get any other value but LightMuted returns nothing for me, how can I get that color? I tried to use it like:

```
            albumart.addEventListener('load', function () {
                var vibrant = new Vibrant(albumart);
                var swatches = vibrant.swatches()
                for (var swatch in swatches)
                    if (swatches.hasOwnProperty(swatch) && swatches[swatch]) {
                    var name = (swatches.LightMuted.getHex()); // Nothing
                    var details = (swatches.DarkVibrant.getHex()); // Returns color
```

Comment: It is not necessary that you get a value for LightMuted everytime. It might me null based on image you choose. Even on landing page on vibrant.js you can see the second image doesn't have LightMuted Attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vibrant.js](https://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/)

> Note that some Swatches might be set to 'undefined' when Vibrant fails to find a matching color for the profile!

You can check the value before

```
var name = swatches.LightMuted ? swatches.LightMuted.getHex() 
                               : '#333' // default value
```

Comment: Is there any way to check if theres no LightMuted color and default to another color?

Comment: @Daniell you can do that check with conditional operator =)

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [Kleur.js](https://github.com/miri-san-so/Kleur) you can use to get images but remember that it gives random color palette every time.

```
// Create the Kleur Object
Kleur = new Kleur();

// Set the image link to get the palette from
imageObj = Kleur.init(imgLink);

// Wait for the image to load
imageObj.onload = function(e) {

    // get the color array from the image
    let colorArr = Kleur.getPixelArray(imageObj);

    // pass the array to generate the color array

    let array_of_pixels = Kleur.generateColorArray(colorArr);

    // get light colors
    const light = Kleur.getLightColors(array_of_pixels);

    // you can get the dominant color from the image
    const dominant = Kleur.getDominant(array_of_pixels);

    // log the light colors and the dominant color
    console.log(light, dominant)
}
```

if you want to see an example for using this code visit the [codepen](https://codepen.io/mirisama/pen/YzXjxew)